# There exists at least one odd bounded eigenstate for finite depth parabolic potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

My attempt :

Let
$$V(x) = \begin{cases}
V_0 \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1 \right), & \text{for } |x|≤a \\
0, & \text{for } |x|>a
\end{cases}$$

Suppose $\psi$ is an odd eigenfunction with eigenvalue $E \in (-V_0, \ 0)$.

Then
$$\psi(x)= \begin{cases}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k d^k x^k\right) e^{-\frac{d^2x^2}{2}}, & \text{for } |x|≤a \\
\psi(x) = C e^{-\sqrt{\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}}x}, & \text{for }x>a
\end{cases}$$

where, $$\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}=\frac{2k+1-\epsilon}{(k+2)(k+1)} $$

$$d= \left(\frac{2mV_0}{\hbar^2a^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}, \ \epsilon = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{V_0}} \frac{a(V_0+E)}{\hbar}.$$

Now I want to show that $\exists E \in (-V_0, \ 0)$ such that $\psi(a-) =\psi(a+)$ and $\psi'(a-) =\psi'(a+)$.

Above is equal to showing that  $\exists E \in (-V_0, \ 0)$ such that $\frac{\sum c_k d^k a^k}{\sum kc_k d^k a^{k-1}-c_k d^{k+2}a^{k+1}}=-\sqrt{\frac{\hbar^2}{-2mE}}$.

How should I proceed? Any hints or reference are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm somewhere wrong, I write it at late night. Anyway, here my thoughts.

Schrödinger equation is a **second**-order differential equation, so you need to define **2** arbitrary constants, which are $c_0$ and $c_1$.
We know that eigenstates must be odd or even, because $[\hat P,\hat H]=0$ (where $\hat P$ is the parity operator). So we can consider only two possibilities:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\ 
c_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
C_m\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\ 
c_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
C_m\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$
where $C_m$ is normalizing constant, which is different for different eigenstates $\psi_m$.

The first choice gives an odd solution. Indeed, the recursive relation $c_{k+2}(c_k)$ sets $c_{2n}=0\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(xd)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{2n+1}(xd)^{2n+1}$, which is an odd function. The function $\exp[-\frac{(xd)^2}{2}]$ is even, so $\psi=\small\text{odd}\normalsize\cdot\small\text{even}$ is odd. Similarly, the second choice in (1) gives an even solution.

For further analysis I used Node Theorem:

> If $\psi_0, \psi_1, \psi_2, ..., \psi_n, ...$ are bound states in 1D-potential (and also there are no degeneracy and continuity of the energy spectrum), then $\psi_n$ has $n$ nodes

(See explanation, for example, [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/video-lectures/part-2/node-theorem/))

Let's find out whether the first odd eigenfunction exists (if there is no the first odd function, then there are no any odd functions). So, the first odd eigenfunction $\psi_1$ has to have a one node. It's possible only if all $c_k=0$ except $c_1$, because the number of zeros is determined by the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(xd)^k$ (the number of zeros equals to the polynomial degree). Then $\psi_1=C_1 \cdot xd\cdot\exp[-\frac{(xd)^2}{2}]$ for $|x|\leqslant a$.

The equation
$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(ad)^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k+1}(k+1)a^kd^{k+1}-c_ka^{k+1}d^{k+2}}=-\sqrt{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2mE}}$$
gives
$$\frac{a}{1-(ad)^2}=-\sqrt{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2mE_1}}$$
A solution exists only if $(ad)^2>1$, otherwise $\sqrt{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2mE_1}}<0$, which isn't possible. In other words:
$$V_0a^2>\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\tag{2}$$
But we also need to make sure that $E_1<0$, which is the condition on the first odd eigenfunction existing:
$$E_1=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2ma^2}((ad)^2-1)^2=-V_0\left(1-\frac{\hbar}{a\sqrt{2mV_0}}\right)^2$$
so, the condition is met. Therefore, **an odd bound state exists, if (2) is right**. Note that (2) guarantees $E_1>-V_0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad V_0a^2>\frac{\hbar^2}{8m}$